# When did the phrase "eat sh*t" enter the English Language?

Tags: etymology, phrases

I'm reading a book, *The Known World* by Edward P. Jones. It is a very well written book about Black slave owners before the Civil War, that is, freed slaves who went on to own slaves themselves.

The book is written with a lot of Southern and Black vernacular which I find very convincing. But I was really jarred on reading the following exchange in chapter 7:

> “Where he say?” the man asked the boy softly.
>
> “Georgia. Where your damn ears?”
>
> The man touched both his earlobes at once and said, “Where they always been.”
>
> “Well, act like it. He said Georgia clear as the damn day and you didn’t even hear him. You closer to him than I am and you still didn’t hear him.” For the very first time ever, Counsel missed the evenings with his family, Laura playing the piano, Belle reading to the younger children. Make up your mind, God, that’s all I ask.
>
> **“You can go eat shit, boy,” the man said. “Pick up your goddamn spoon and eat shit.”**

I first heard that phrase as a teenager, and just assumed it was made up sometime shortly before or during my lifetime. Reading it in a book set in the mid-1800s felt like I had stumbled on an anachronism. I wondered when the phrase was actually first used in English (and thought, "I know the place to ask.")

I knew [shit](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=shit) was an old word (as a noun, since 1580s, as a verb, even earlier then that), but how old is the phrase *"eat shit"*?

Marginalia in illuminated manuscripts were sometimes very irreverent, and I
have seen some with eating of feces depicted, so it seems entirely possible that this was not an unknown phrase. Also, Sir John Harington in *The metamorphosis of Ajax: a cloacinean satire* (1596) makes a punitive fantasy of coprophagia, in feeding "poore hungrie fellowes” "all the fat offerings" made in London's privies. So... it is possible that it's very olde.

<sub>I don't like vulgarity; please forgive me. I was just really taken by surprise by coming across the phrase in a very well-written book. I don't mean to bring EL&U down. But if [Jonathan Swift](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/180934) can use the word in a poem, I think it's fair game here.</sub>

Comment: @Mitch: You're certainly a cheeky sod! Funny, but cheeky!

Comment: The earliest viewable match that Google Books finds for the exact two-word phrase is from 1949 in A.I. Bezzerides, [_Thieves Market_](https://books.google.com/books?id=Akc_Gsij-gwC&pg=PA157&dq=%22eat+shit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu-uXU4MbKAhVD-GMKHVdlAw0Q6AEINTAE#v=onepage&q=%22eat%20shit%22&f=false). A couple of months ago, I happened to see the movie based on this novel, called [_Thieves Highway_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041958/combined) (also 1949), directed by Jules Dassin. It's excellent—however, the screenplay doesn't included the fateful expletive in the dialogue.

Comment: @SvenYargs: I found *This House Against this House*, Vincent Sheean, [p 317](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-2oZAAAAIAAJ&dq=%27%22What+can+you+do+with+a+people+who+eat+shit%3F%22+the+American+soldier+says%3B+and+the+habits+of+the+Hindus+with+cow+dung+are+perhaps+the+most+specific+shock+of+all+these+I+am+enumerating.%27&focus=searchwithinvolume), Random House, 1946 with *("What can you do with a people who eat shit?" the American soldier says; and the habits of the Hindus with cow dung are perhaps the most specific shock of all these I am enumerating.)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I restricted my search to 'eat shit', although I included that phrase with the variant spellings 'shite', 'sh*t', 'sh-t', and 's--t', where possible. I also included the various inflections of 'eat'.

A troublesome instance in [*Supplemental Nights*](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31175021006302;view=1up;seq=102;size=125), 1888 (R.F. Burton), returned from a search for 'eat shite', footnoted "to eat skite" (as meaning "to talk or act foolishly") in reference to text reading "devour ordure":

[image] 
[image]

The *OED Online* does not give 'skite' as a variant spelling of 'shite'.

The earliest unalloyed figurative use I uncovered was from a novel titled [*The Folded Leaf*](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015066081467;view=1up;seq=76), published in 1945. This text clip is the excerpt from Google Books results:

[image: eat shit]

The next appearance was not visually verifiable, as it occurred in a "restricted rights" novel about life in the infantry, [*Toward an Unknown Station*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cPfSAAAAMAAJ&q=%22eat%20shit%22&dq=%22eat%20shit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK5vey78bKAhUI62MKHatTDhsQ6AEIJjAC) (Allan Lyon), published in 1948:

> "You *eat shit*," Ben told him. "Goldbricking while I work my ass off!" We all helped him hide his cache, and then we settled down happily to wait for chow, thinking of the stolen feast we would enjoy later in the afternoon.

---

Regarding the appearance of 'shit' (absent 'eat') in print prior to 1900, J. Wright, in [*The English dialect dictionary*, volume 5](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc2.ark:/13960/t5k93gh82;view=1up;seq=403;size=175) (EDD), compiled a fair-sized collection of dialect uses from the 1600s through the 1800s, some dated. These are clippings of the primary entries:

[image: eatshit4]
[image: eatshit5]

Nowhere in Wright's collection, neither in Volume 5's main entries nor in Volume 2's entries for 'eat', did I find the 'eat shit' phrase.

Eric Partridge, in his annotated 1963 edition of the third edition of F. Grose's [*A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue*](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015015372702;view=1up;seq=206) (full text not available; the link is to the 1796 edition of Grose), provides a good summary of the use of 'shit' in the early 1900s. In the snapshot below this paragraph, Partridge's historical summary begins with "--In 1914-1918 ...", and his summary of the senses found in EDD appears after "--Dialect has many ...". The surrounding material in Partridge's annotation is based on information from the *Oxford Dictionary* (OD).

[image: eatshit6]

---

Regarding other negative results, the phrase 'eat shit' did not appear in my searches of

- *The Slang Dictionary*, 1865 (Hotten)
- *The American Slang Dictionary*, 1891 (Maitland)
- *A dictionary of slang, jargon & cant embracing English, American, and Anglo-Indian slang, pidgin English, gypsies' jargon and other irregular phraseology*, 1897 (Barrère)
- *A new dictionary of the terms ancient and modern of the canting crew, in its several tribes, of Gypsies, beggers, thieves, cheats, &c., with an addition of some proverbs, phrases, figurative speeches, &c.*, 1899 (Gent)
- *A new dictionary of Americanisms; being a glossary of words supposed to be peculiar to the United States and the dominion of Canada*, 1902? (Clapin)
- *A Dictionary of Slang and Colloquial English*, 1921 and 1909, original issue 1890 (Farmer & Henley; I checked both the abridged, 1921, and the seven-volume revised edition, 1909)

Of those, I could expect with a reasonable degree of certainty that if the phrase 'eat shit' had much currency in English prior to the 1900s, it would've been likely to appear in Farmer & Henley.

---

Altogether,

1. the absence of the phrase 'eat shit' in Wright's apparently comprehensive dialect collection,
2. as well as Partridge's failure to mention the phrase in his annotation of Grose,
3. along with the phrase's non-appearance in any of the six other sources in the bulleted list (including especially Farmer & Henley),
4. and the OED's earliest attesting quote being 1955 (unless you count 'crap' in 1930),

suggest that, with the troublesome exception of Burton's footnote, the earliest appearance in print of 'eat shit' may be the use in the 1945 novel, *The Folded Leaf*.

Nonetheless, it is unreasonable to suppose that 1945 use is, in fact, the earliest appearance of the phrase in print; the 1945 use is merely the earliest print appearance I could uncover with a limited set of resources.

Further, aside from appearance in print, the use of the phrase 'eat shit' in dialectal speech before the 1900s, even dialectal speech in antebellum Virginia, is not unreasonable--merely unlikely.

Answer (score 8):

In print, people may not have been ordering others to **eat shit** before the 1940s, but the euphemistic expression ***eat dung*** is much older.

Ngram plots “eat dung” (red line) starting from 1800s

[image]

> When a few days after the Rais (one of the mullahs who watch over the people, and have power to flog any one who does not observe strictly the Muhammedan religion) sent one of his friends to Stoddart and asked him whether he was an Eljee (ambassador) or a Sodagur (merchant)? Stoddart replied **“Eat dung!”**
>
> His imprisonment upon this occasion the Nayeb passed over in silence, and continued, At last from fear, Stoddart said he would become a Mussulman, and according to the Muhammedan religion, if a person says he will turn Mussulman, he must either do so or die. He became a Mussulman and a short time after openly avowed again the Christian religion.

*[Narrative of a Mission to Bokhara, in the Years 1843-1845](https://books.google.it/books?id=zHgOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA344&dq=%22eat%20dung%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip8sOOgsbKAhVDBSwKHWqgAlQ4FBDoAQgjMAE#v=onepage&q=%22eat%20dung%22&f=false)* (1845) By Joseph Wolff

Other instances of “eat dung” appear in [Isaiah 36:12](https://books.google.it/books?id=7JgXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR48-IA59&dq=%22eat%20dung%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj17vCkh8bKAhUG0xoKHeZOCts4MhDoAQgqMAI#v=onepage&q=%22eat%20dung%22&f=false), the excerpt dated **1808** describes what will befall Jerusalem if it were besieged.

[image]

From **1631**, *A commentarie upon all the Epistles of the Apostle Saint Paul, etc.*

([Link](https://books.google.it/books?id=HfhiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA191&dq=%22eat%20dung%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrne-cjMbKAhWFtRQKHeAQC50Q6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=%22eat%20dung%22&f=false))
[image]

> Only the feare of fornication is the cause of this grant. As if a man were directed to eat bread made of fine wheat flower, but being pinched with hunger through the want hereof, and so ready to eat dung, it were permitted to him (rather than doe so) to eat barley bread. And it is to be noted, that he faith not, Let every man marry a wife, but *Let him have his owne wife.*

Finally, if one looks at the etymology of *[**dirt**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dirt)* one finds that it originally meant excrement (probably the human kind) and the verb, to defecate.

> 15c. metathesis of Middle English *drit*, *drytt* "mud, dirt, **dung**" (**c. 1300**), from Old Norse *drit*, cognate with Old English *dritan* "**to void excrement**," from Proto-Germanic *dritan (cognates: Dutch drijten, Old High German trizan). Used abusively of persons from c. 1300.

*The Dictionary of American Slang*'s entry for “[eat dirt](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eat--dirt)” says

> To accept rebuke or harassment meekly; swallow one's pride; eat shit: *I ate dirt and apologized to that bastard* (1857+)

The two word phrase **eat dirt** was therefore a mid-nineteenth century euphemism for the more obscene *shit*, and the explicit *dung*; however its power to shock and offend has decreased over the years, and it is probably for this reason that the author Edward P. Jones substituted the chronological (but now tame) *eat dirt* with its more shocking, and taboo counterpart.

Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eat+dirt!%2Ceat+dung%2Ceat+shit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceat%20dirt%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceat%20dung%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceat%20shit%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ceat%20dirt%20!%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ceat%20dung%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ceat%20shit%3B%2Cc1) shows that the idiom *eat dirt !* (blue line) dominates over *eat dung* (red line) but is rarely used nowadays compared to more recently coined, and cruder, *eat shit* (green line).

[image]

It goes without saying that *eat dirt!* can be taken literally and figuratively, and it needn't always refer to excrement—*dirt* also means "soil"—but it's worthwhile noting its peak between 1840 and 1860.

An excerpt from *[Hammel, the Obeah Man.](https://books.google.it/books?id=VcMvAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA129&dq=%22eat%20dirt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVrtqLl8zKAhWCJg8KHfiOCroQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=%22eat%20dirt%22&f=false)* 1827

> “ ... Begone! The ants shall gnaw your bones, and the vultures struggle for your flesh ! I curse you by the spirits of earth and of hell ! Your joints shall be rottenness, and you shall eat dirt like the worms !—Tremble, and begone !”

Comment: Sounds like a euphemism just for print

Comment: Nice catch with Isaiah 36:12.

Comment: Note, too, that _coprophagous_ ("feeding on dung") goes back to 1826, according to Merriam-Webster.

Comment: I can't find the story you are referring to. You may post it if you like.

Comment: No time, maybe later

Comment: OED confirms that "eat dirt" is the earlier version of "eat shit" and gives the 1857 citation: " *C. Kingsley Two Years Ago II. v. 200*   You have wonderfully changed your tone. Who was to eat any amount of dirt, if he could but save his influence thereby?"

Comment: Um...there's a logic problem with considering 'eat dirt' or 'eat dung' euphemisms for 'eat shit', because 'eat dirt' and 'eat dung' are evidently of earlier origin, as you point out. Substituting a mild or indirect expression for one considered more offensive requires that the more offensive expression be in use and rejected in favor of the indirect and mild expression. Interesting, fun 'answer' though!

Comment: @JEL etymonline says: [The notion that it ("shit") is a recent word might be partly because it was taboo from c. 1600 and rarely appeared in print (neither Shakespeare nor the KJV has it), and even in "vulgar" publications of the late 18c. it is disguised by dashes. It drew the wrath of censors as late as 1922 ("Ulysses" and "The Enormous Room"),](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=shit) So people definitely knew the term, more likely than not used it in speech but it was never seen in print.

Comment: Yes, 'shit' is an old word. OED finds attestation in print in various forms from early Old English, including quotes with dashes in place of letters, and the 1277 surname, Richard *Scittebagge*. It's the phrase that's in doubt. OED only attests that from 1955 (with a 1930 "eat crap"), and states that the phrase is *trans. coarse slang (orig. U.S.)*.

Comment: So my reference to "second half of 1800s" is not inconsistent!

Comment: No, but it referred to "eat dirt" not "eat shit". You should have read the link "eat dirt" that was cited by AHD :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I saw that too, about the word being taboo, and suspect that "eat sh*t" was common much earlier than it appears in print. In the marginalia of illuminated manuscripts (c.1000-1400s), the act is often depicted in very scathing manners (bishops eating some, etc.) Clearly it was, well, not a rare curse?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very informative (as always!)

Comment: @medica my pleasure, it's disappointing that the question received poor/negative feedback. Once I started looking into the origin of "eat shit" it became quite fascinating.

Comment: The reasons for why the question received so little attention was probably due to some users feeling physically disgusted by the topic, (in this day and age?) and  the semi-apologetic ending.  Why the need to apologize or cite Jonathan Swift? The question was strictly about language and the idiom's history.

Comment: The apology was sincere; I felt awkward bringing it to the site. If people hold that against me, there's nothing I can do about it. I was happy for answerers who took the question seriously. :)

Answer (score 3):

The expression appears to be from the second half of the 19th century.

***[Eat shit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eat-shit):***

> - Also, eat crap. Submit to degrading treatment, as in He refused to eat shit from the coach. James T. Farrell had the one term in Grandeur (1930), 
>     “They don't eat nobody's crap,” and Mario Puzo the other in Dark Arena (1955), “He'd eaten shit all week.” ***(second half of 1800s)***

The American Heritage Idioms Dictionary

Comment: @Josh - What does your emboldened italicised '1800s' comment refer to?

Comment: https://books.google.it/books?id=Akc_Gsij-gwC&pg=PA157&dq=%22eat+shit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2gbuuksbKAhVCPxQKHfKOAT04FBDoAQg5MAU#v=onepage&q=%22eat%20shit%22&f=false 1949 from Google Ngram.

Comment: I wonder whether "eat crap" was a euphemism.  It lacks sufficient force imho.

Comment: @Dan - It is not my comment, if you click in the  red link in my answer you can see it is an information  provided by the cited source.

Answer (score 1):

The words "eat shit", used in the sense of "Go to Hell!", first appear in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eat+shit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceat%20shit%3B%2Cc0) in the 50s.

But, as it's a fairly rude phrase, it's use, prior to the "let it all hang out" 60s, was probably rarely recorded on durable media, even if it was spoken with fair frequency.

(Speaking as someone born in 1949, I never got the impression that the expression was somehow "new".  I had a fairly sheltered youth, but I did hear it on occasion.)

One does need to be a little careful about "sightings", though, as the words can appear in a context such as "I didn't eat shit for three days and I was incredibly hungry when I finally got to the camp."